# Ruby Regex to add a space after period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am using regular expression to add a space after period. I have the following regex which searches for a period with no space.

```
"This is new test.This is new test".gsub(/[.]+[^ ]+/, ". ")
```

But its replacing ".This" with period and space. I want the output to be

```
"This is new test. This is new test"(note there is a space after period)
```

Comment: What if the period is a decimal separator?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its a normal sentence with only alphabets. It wont have any decimals

Comment: Then use the solution in the linked question, only replace the comma with `\.`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Just to explain: the `[^ ]+` is a consuming pattern. Once you convert it to a `(?! )` lookahead, a zero-width assertion, you no longer put the matched text to the match value, and thus only a dot will be replaced.

Comment: In the case you have `"One. Two.Three."` that would add an additional whitespace between `.` and `Two`, what to do there?

Comment: Aaah `\.(?!\s)` thanks!

Comment: I added a non-regex solution to the question for which this question is a dup.